# undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigation.navigate') in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have one button which is redirect to anothe page called **SELECT_COMPANY_SCREEN**.only i need to redirect to this page.

```
import { SELECT_COMPANY_SCREEN } from "../../constants/screen-names";
const SettingsCompanyCard = ({ navigation }) => {
<Button
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate("SELECT_COMPANY_SCREEN")}
        title="go to Company"
      />
}
export default SettingsCompanyCard;
```

but i am facing issues like below.
[image]
How can i resolve this issue?

Comment: In your Navigation Setup is the Screen also called: SELECT_COMPANY_SCREEN ?

Answer (score 0):

I think I had the same issue a while ago.

If your SteeingsComapnyCard component isn't the component you set as component in your Screen-component, you can pass the prop navigation from its parent:

When defining, just do `<SettingsCompanyCard navigation={navigation} />`

Comment: i have applied this one.but i am getting error for above both logic.
```
If you're trying to navigate to a screen in a nested navigator, see https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators#navigating-to-a-screen-in-a-nested-navigator.

This is a development-only warning and won't be shown in production.
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @ChinmayeeSahoo Are you using nested navigators? If so, the  [docs about that](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators#navigating-to-a-screen-in-a-nested-navigator) help a lot, otherwise please update the question so I can see your code

Answer (score -1):

use props.

```
const SettingsCompanyCard = (props) => {
 <Button
    onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate("SELECT_COMPANY_SCREEN")}
    title="go to Company"
  />
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `this.props.navigation.navigate('Your screename')`